# Hint that dictionary argument will not be modified

Tags: c#

How can I hint that the dictionary will not be updated?

```cs
public void MyMethod(IDictionary dictionary)
{
    ...
}
```

So that callers have contractual security that the dictionary they pass to `MyMethod` will not have any values set, any values added, etc.

It will only have values read from it.

I don't want to restrict the parameter type, the caller should be able to pass whatever dictionary they want.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier

Comment: Do you know the key and value types statically? In that case you can use[`IReadOnlyDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2?view=net-5.0).

Comment: If you have `IDictionary`, I could call this method with an implementation that modifies the dictionary when you read values from it. So you can't guarantee that your method doesn't modify the dictionary.

Comment: @Maroun, I'm afraid that `in` modifier will not prevent dictionary from modification with something like `dictionary.Add(k,v);`

Comment: Have you thought of documentation comments? Just specify it and it will be highlighted when the user hovers over your function.

Comment: If you mean "Any type implementing IDictionary" then apart from documenting it there is nothing else you can do. If you can switch to using IReadOnlyDictionary then that would be better but IDictionary does not require IReadOnlyDictionary so there could be types implementing IDictionary but not IReadOnlyDictionary and thus be ineligible.

Comment: It sounds like documentation is the best solution then. Thank you all for the help.